# How do I invoke a powershell script to define a function so one can use it in the calling powershell script?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Suppose I have scripts AAA.ps1 and script BBB.ps1.  Assume they are in the same location (directory).

Script BBB.ps1 defines a function `BFunc` which I want to invoke from AAA.ps1

How do I modify AAA.ps1  so that it can define-and-use `BFunc`?

As a test I have tried the following two commands in a script.

```
 & "$PSScriptRoot\BBB.ps1"
 get-childitem function:* | Select-Object Name | where { $_ -match "BFunc" }
```

If the above worked then I should see some output that `BFunc` is defined but nothing comes out.

Comment: Try using `.` instead of `&`

Comment: as rpm192 pointed out, use "dot-sourcing" ... this article may help a tad ... Exploring Dot-Sourcing in PowerShell -- Microsoft Certified Professional Magazine Online — https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/02/02/exploring-dot-sourcing-in-powershell.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Ah, sometimes it is too simple.   It turns out that what PS expects is that BBB.ps1 be *included* into AAA.ps1.    This means that the AAA.ps1 file could look like this:

```
. "$PSScriptRoot\BBB.ps1"
get-childitem function:* | Select-Object Name | where { $_ -match "BFunc" }
```

And that works!